# Recursive function for update

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a treelist that contains folders. Each folder can have files or other folders inside.

I need a function in C# that if I change the visibility of the folder, automatically they have to change the visibility of the folders and files under it.

Could you help me out?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are rendering your list in and depending on the UI and/or framework you are using there may be other ways to achieve this but the simple approach to walking your folder structure would be using some simple recursion. An example:

```
public class Resource
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public bool Visible { get; set; }
    public List<Resource> Children { get; set; }
}


public class Form
{
    public void ChangeVisibility(Resource resource)
    {
        if (resource.Type != "Folder") return;

        resource.Visible = !resource.Visible;

        if (resource.Children.Any())
        {
            resource.Children.ForEach(ChangeVisibility);
        }
    }     
}
```